# Ways to convert a large data set from SQL Server to Azure SQL?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-data-lake

I've a large table with 500 million rows which I need to import to Azure SQL database.

I'm able successfully import smaller set by converting the table to .CSV file and importing it as a table in Azure SQL database. However, the table that I have to import is huge and wondering, how to do the same.

Following is the code sample to import a small table.

```
    file_location = "/FileStore/tables/data.csv"
    file_type = "csv"

    # CSV options
    infer_schema = "false"
    first_row_is_header = "true"
    delimiter = ","

    # The applied options are for CSV files. For other file types, these will be ignored.
    df = spark.read.format(file_type) \
      .option("inferSchema", infer_schema) \
      .option("header", first_row_is_header) \
      .option("sep", delimiter) \
      .load(file_location)

    display(df)


permanent_table_name = "data"

df.write.format("parquet").saveAsTable(permanent_table_name)
```

Comment: What is your data source server? Is it on-premise SQL Server? Can you create a linked server or use SSIS?

Comment: You can also try DTSWizard.exe which is very easy to use.

Comment: How many GB? Is Azure close to you and you have good latency?

Comment: It is around 500 GB. I'm planning to split the files by 1GB and transfer them to Azure datalake. After the files are transferred,then create a SQL table and copy the files from datalake to the Azure sql table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you table has large data(about 500 GB), maybe you can think about to use the [Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/).

Here's the [Copy performance and scalability achievable using ADF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-performance#copy-performance-and-scalability-achievable-using-adf):
[image]

There two tutorial can helps  you:

1. [Copy data to and from SQL Server by using Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-sql-server)
2. [Copy data to or from Azure SQL Database by using Azure Data
   Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-sql-database)

You also can improve the copy performance by this document [Copy activity performance and scalability guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-performance).

Hope this helps.